# ASP.NET MVC Show a list of data in any view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to ASP.NET so I may not be wording this correctly but what I am trying to do is show a list of data say on my home page from my database. Now normally I would do all the usual stuff like write some SQL in the controller and then do a foreach loop in the View. But how would I do this for something I want to show on multiple pages like a sidebar of the latest news items?

If anyone can give me some examples of this in use (downloadable solutions would be great) it'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What view engine are you using?  If you're unsure, it's probably either ASPX or Razor (.cshtml)

Answer (score 2):

You should create an action and view that render that list alone, then render the action in your Master / Layout page by calling `Html.RenderAction`.

Comment: With regards to the View though wouldn't I technically end up with a fake View? e.g. /News/SidebarNews for that Action

Comment: Wouldn't I use like a partial view or something?

Comment: @Cameron: Yes; it would be a partial view.

Comment: Are they any downloadable solutions I could get to have a play with? Something dead simple where it has a sidebar showing 3 items from a database on the home page using a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could create Base controller class, which will fetch general data for your site: news, menu.